# Sorting in a Metal compute shader

Tags: ios, graphics, gpgpu, metal

Does Metal have functionality similar to CUDA's thrust::sort or is one expected to write their own sort function?

Comment: CUDA does not have one either. [Thrust](https://thrust.github.io/) is a 3rd party library that offers interoperability with CUDA, TBB, OpenMP and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Accelerate framework has useful vector operations in the vDSP package.  Sorting, specifically, can be found here.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/reversing_and_sorting_functions